# IOS how to judge sandbox has been changed (device jailbreak)

Tags: ios

Our company has an finance app，now，The demand is that，In order to prevent data  been tampered in  jailbreak device, I thought of the two methods，

1. We must judge sandbox when we open the app, is there some ways to
   judge sandbox has been changed(i don't how to do).
2. Get ipa file in my code and do the hash operation，compare with server data（but I don't know how to get ipa file in my code.

Comment: A user can access the data on a non-jailbroken device too. There is no reason to check for a jailbroken device.

Comment: The code files are signed encrypted and signed by Apple, they are not subject to change.

Comment: If there is data that is valuable ($$$, you say it is a financial app) there is only one solution, get help from a cryptographic domain expert. At a minimum help designing the security and a review of the completed code and app. That is what I do. Figure on several thousand dollars minimum. Otherwise wait for the successful attack.

Comment: Define what is valuable and the amount. Define the attacker, competency level and time/money they are willing to spend. Defending from the user is very difficult as is a well funded government. Keep in mind that 100% security is not possible, all security is just increasing the work factor.

Comment: Thank all of you, I know how to say with the company。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandbox is a concept, it means only the app has the authority to do some allowed operation. I don't think there is a way to judge sandbox. But instead, you can judge your data wether it's been modified.

So it comes to the data encryption. You can focus on how to encrypt your core data which has much value.